# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead getting right json key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am useing this plugin for an ajax auto complete feature
https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead
the bootstrap-3 type. The code below is working but I do not know why it works. Specifically how the the process  and response parameter work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#typeahead-input').typeahead({
        autoSelect: true,
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 400,
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/location',
                data: {sstr: query},
                dataType: 'json'
            })
                .done(function(response) {

                    // console.log(response)
                    return process(response);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

my json looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "123", 
        "name": "Frederiksted", 
        "state": "VI", 
        "zip_code": "840"
    }
]
```

What if i wanted to autocomplete to populated based on on the zip_code field how would i do it?
I have tried doing "response.zipcode" but it comes out as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, response.zipcode will be undefined because response is a Array not a Object. You access zipcode by response[0].zip_code ( And also note that your property name is not 'zipcode' it is 'zip_code' ).

Second, documentation of the "source" property says: The data source to query against. May be an array of strings, an array of JSON object with a name property or a function.

So, what you give to the "process" method most probably should be a array of strings or array of JSON objects where each JSON object has a "name" property.
If your response is correct and returns an array of objects like you say, 
then it means your objects each have a 'name' property,so that property is displayed. If you want to display something else, you need to create a new String array from the response:

So I would try this:

```
 .done(function(response) {
     // get the response and create a new array of Strings
     var names = $.map (response, function(item) {
          return item.name + '-' + item.zip_code;
     });
     // console.log(response)
     return process(names);
    });
```

or another way:

```
.done(function(response) {
 // get the response and change the 'name' of each object
 $.each (response, function() {
       this.name = this.name + '-' + this.zip_code;
 });
 // console.log(response)
 return process(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank You for this. The code youprovided worked Beautifully. But what if i only wanted the zip_code whould i do just?  $.each (response, function() {
       this.name = this.zip_code;
 });? its not working for me when i search for zip_code

Comment: i dont think the plugin auto completes with numbers but with names thankyou for your help

Comment: try converting the numbers to strings  this.name=this.zip_code.toString();

Comment: and btw, zipcodes are usually stored as Strings instead of Numbers which makes it easier to validate with String length validators and etc. If something is not used in numeric calculations or comparisons, it is possibly a String not a Number.

Comment: Thank You your so smart. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue with json format:

[ 
  "id": "123", 
  "name": "Frederiksted", 
  "state": "VI", 
  "zip_code": "840" 
]

Comment: check this url to see, working example how it works.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.that example doesn't clear anything up. It doesnt show how to use diffrent keys for the mutiselect